# Proving $(A\cup B)\cap(B\cup C)\cap(C\cup A)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Proving $(A\cup B)\cap(B\cup C)\cap(C\cup A)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$?

I managed to prove one side by saying:

Let E=LHS and F=RHS

> Let $ x \in E$. Then $x \in (A\cup B) \lor \ x \in (B\cup C) \lor \ x \in
> (C\cup A).$ If $x\notin A$, then $x$ must be in $B$ and $C$. If $x\notin B$, then $x$ must be in $A$ and $C$. If $x \notin C$, then $x$ is in $B$ and $A$. Therefore $x \in F$ and $ E \subset F $.

I'm having trouble proving the other direction. Can I prove it in a similar way saying that let $x \in F$, if $x \notin A$, then $x$ would be in $B$ and $C$? That doesn't make sense to me. Another way I thought of solving it would be:

Let $x \in F. $ Then

- if $x \in A$, then  $x \in B \cup  C$,
- If $x \in B$, then $x \in A \cup C$.
- if $x \in C$, then $x \in B \cup A$

And then is this sufficient to show that $ x \in F, thus \ F \subset E \ and \ E=F $?

Comment: If $x\in F$ then your three cases are $x\in A\cap B$ or $x\in A\cap C$ or $x\in B\cap C.$ Which case are you having trouble with? Observe that $A\cap B\subset A\subset A\cup B$ and $A\cap C\subset C\subset B\cup C$ and $B\cap C\subset C\subset C\cup A.$

Comment: An alternative, and maybe longer proof, is manipulating algebraically the LHS (or the RHS) to show that is equal to the other part. These manipulations we will use the knowledge of the properties of the operations $\cup$ and $\cap$ basically.

Comment: @Masacroso I tried the longer proof, but I kept getting mixed up. Personally, writing out all the cases is much more helpful for me to fully visualize the problem. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an element is in $F$ then it is either in $A$ and $B$, or $A$ and $C$, or $B$ and $C$.

If it is in $A$ and $B$, then $\ldots$ *Abaracdabara.* $\ldots$  therefore it is in $(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$, which is $E$.

We can likewise show the same inference for the other two cases.  Hence anything in $F$ is in $E$, demonstrating that $F\subseteq E$ as required.

Comment: OH, thank you so much! Ah, this makes so much sense now. As a sidenote, was my previous proof for E in F alright?

Comment: @Nikitau  Yes.  You demonstrated that if an element of $E$ was not in any one of the sets, then it must be in both of the others, which means it is in $F$.